# WooCommerce checkout field integer/numerical

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I got this nice plugin that creates a custom shipping field:
Street and housenumber, how can I make the housenumber field only allow integers/numerical value's?

I am asking this because customers are still being to stupid to fill in their housenumber. Instead of their housenumber they are writing their streetname in the housenumber field.

```
    function wc_hn_plugins_loaded() {
load_plugin_textdomain( 'wc_hn', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wc_hn_plugins_loaded' );

/**
* WooCommerce house number checkout fields
* 
* @param array $fields
* @return array
*/
function wc_hn_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
// Fields
$field_street = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Street', 'wc_hn' ),
    'placeholder' => _x( 'Street', 'placeholder', 'wc_hn' ),
    'required'    => true,
    'class'       => array( 'form-row-first', 'street-field' ),
    'clear'       => false
);

$field_house_number = array(
    'label'       => __( 'House Number', 'wc_hn' ),
    'placeholder' => _x( 'Number', 'placeholder', 'wc_hn' ),
    'required'    => true,
    'class'       => array( 'form-row-last', 'house-number-field' ),
    'clear'       => false
);

$field_house_number_extra = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Extra', 'wc_hn' ),
    'placeholder' => _x( 'Extra', 'placeholder', 'wc_hn' ),
    'required'    => false,
    'class'       => array( 'form-row-last', 'house-number-extra-field' ),
    'clear'       => true
);

// Position
$position = 3;

// Billing fields
if ( isset( $fields['billing'] ) ) {
    $fields_billing = &$fields['billing'];

    // Remove the deafult address fields
    unset( $fields_billing['billing_address_1'] );
    unset( $fields_billing['billing_address_2'] );

    // Add the new address fields
    $fields_billing_new = array();
    $fields_billing_new['billing_street']             = $field_street;
    $fields_billing_new['billing_house_number']       = $field_house_number;
    $fields_billing_new['billing_house_number_extra'] = $field_house_number_extra;

    $fields_billing = array_slice( $fields_billing, 0, $position, true ) + $fields_billing_new + array_slice( $fields_billing, $position, null, true );
}

// Shipping fields 
if ( isset( $fields['shipping'] ) ) {
    $fields_shipping = &$fields['shipping'];

    // Remove the default address fields
    unset( $fields_shipping['shipping_address_1'] );
    unset( $fields_shipping['shipping_address_2'] );

    // Add the new address fields
    $fields_shipping_new = array();
    $fields_shipping_new['shipping_street']             = $field_street;
    $fields_shipping_new['shipping_house_number']       = $field_house_number;
    $fields_shipping_new['shipping_house_number_extra'] = $field_house_number_extra;

    $fields_shipping = array_slice( $fields_shipping, 0, $position, true ) + $fields_shipping_new + array_slice( $fields_shipping, $position, null, true );
}

return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_hn_checkout_fields' );

 /**
 * Update order meta
 * @see https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.0.12/classes/class-      wc-checkout.php#L359
  * @see https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.0.12/classes/class-wc-checkout.php#L15
  * 
  * @param string $order_id
  * @param array $posted array of posted form data
  */
function wc_hn_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {
// Billing address 1
$street             = isset( $posted['billing_street'] ) ? woocommerce_clean(     $posted['billing_street'] ) : '';
$house_number       = isset( $posted['billing_house_number'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $posted['billing_house_number'] ) : '';
$house_number_extra = isset( $posted['billing_house_number_extra'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $posted['billing_house_number_extra'] ) : '';

$billing_address_1 = trim( sprintf( 
    '%s %s %s', 
    $street, 
    $house_number,
    $house_number_extra
) );

// @see https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.0.12/admin/post-types/writepanels/writepanel-order_data.php#L721
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_address_1', $billing_address_1 );

// Shipping address 1
$street             = isset( $posted['shipping_street'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $posted['shipping_street'] ) : '';
$house_number       = isset( $posted['shipping_house_number'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $posted['shipping_house_number'] ) : '';
$house_number_extra = isset( $posted['shipping_house_number_extra'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $posted['shipping_house_number_extra'] ) : '';

$shipping_address_1 = trim( sprintf(
    '%s %s %s',
    $street,
    $house_number,
    $house_number_extra
) );

if ( empty( $shipping_address_1 ) ) {
    // Use billing address as shipping adres 1
    $shipping_address_1 = $billing_address_1;
}

// @see https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.0.12/admin/post-types/writepanels/writepanel-order_data.php#L732
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_1', $shipping_address_1 );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',     'wc_hn_checkout_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );

 /**
 * Enqueue plugin style-file
 */
 function wc_hn_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'wc-hn-style', plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_hn_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: No comments yet, no one has a solution for this?